# Missing operator or semicolon

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
procedure TMainWin.AgeEBKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
procedure ProcessInput(Sender:Tobject);
  var age : byte;
begin
  Age := StrToInt(AgeEB.Text);
  Age := Age+2;
  AnsLbl.visible := True   //it's here, where there is a mistake
  AnsLbl.Caption := 'Bad luck, I"m' + IntTostr(Age) + '-Years old'
  if not (Key in ['0'..'9' , chr(vk_return), chr(vk_back)]) then begin
    key := #0;
    exit

  end
```

This is the code, there is some thing wrong with it, but

Comment: The error tells you **exactly** what the problem is, and **exactly** where it is (you've even added a comment at that point). What more do you want us to do for you? You know exactly what is wrong, and precisely where it's happening - do you want us to come by to work the keyboard for you to add the missing semicolon? Also, we don't do URGENT or ASAP here; if you need immediate attention for your issue, hire a contractor or consultant and pay them well enough to provide that level of response.

Comment: ... i just started on delphi... i didn't know that you must add a ; to every end of the line....

Comment: As I said, the error message is quite clear, if you actually *read the words*. It's important to learn to do so.

Comment: Which book, tutorial, or instructor are you using to learn Delphi? Whatever you're using hasn't taught you even the most basic of syntax rules. You should strongly consider using a different resource instead.

Answer (score 6):

Statements need to be separated using the separator symbol, `;`.

In the following code, you fail to do this:

```
AnsLbl.visible := True 
AnsLbl.Caption := 'Bad luck, I"m' + IntTostr(Age) + '-Years old'
if ...
```

You must place separators between these three statements. Typically they are placed at the end of each line like so:

```
AnsLbl.visible := True;
AnsLbl.Caption := 'Bad luck, I"m' + IntTostr(Age) + '-Years old';
if ...
```

But they need not be. You could equally write this as:

```
AnsLbl.visible := True
; AnsLbl.Caption := 'Bad luck, I"m' + IntTostr(Age) + '-Years old'
; if ...
```

That would be very weird and I am not advocating that you do so. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Tokens) says this:

> **Tokens**
>
> On the simplest level, a program is a sequence of tokens delimited by
>   separators. A token is the smallest meaningful unit of text in a
>   program. A separator is either a blank or a comment. Strictly
>   speaking, it is not always necessary to place a separator between two
>   tokens; for example, the code fragment:
>
> ```
> Size:=20;Price:=10;
> ```
>
> is perfectly legal. Convention and readability, however, dictate that
>   we write this in two lines, as:
>
> ```
> Size := 20;
> Price := 10;
> ```
>
> Tokens are categorized as special symbols, identifiers, reserved
>   words, directives, numerals, labels, and character strings. A
>   separator can be part of a token only if the token is a character
>   string. Adjacent identifiers, reserved words, numerals, and labels
>   must have one or more separators between them.

The documentation also has this to say about [compound statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Compound_Statements):

> **Compound Statements**
>
> A compound statement is a sequence of other (simple or structured)
>   statements to be executed in the order in which they are written. The
>   compound statement is bracketed by the reserved words begin and end,
>   and its constituent statements are separated by semicolons. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> begin
>   Z := X;
>   X := Y;
>   X := Y;
> end;
> ```
>
> The last semicolon before end is optional. So this could have been
>   written as:
>
> ```
> begin
>   Z := X;
>   X := Y;
>   Y := Z
> end;
> ```
>
> Compound statements are essential in contexts where Delphi syntax
>   requires a single statement. In addition to program, function, and
>   procedure blocks, they occur within other structured statements, such
>   as conditionals or loops. For example:
>
> ```
> begin
>   I := SomeConstant;
>   while I > 0 do
>   begin
>     ...
>     I := I - 1;
>   end;
> end;
> ```
>
> You can write a compound statement that contains only a single
>   constituent statement; like parentheses in a complex term, begin and
>   end sometimes serve to disambiguate and to improve readability. You
>   can also use an empty compound statement to create a block that does
>   nothing:
>
> ```
> begin
> end;
> ```

Answer (score -1):

It has been a while since i did any Delphi coding but I think you need ; semicolon at the end of each line.

Like for instance this line:

```
AnsLbl.visible := True
```

should be:

```
AnsLbl.visible := True;
```

Comment: Thanks! That Worked!

Comment: No, you do not need a semicolon at the end of every line.